# how to loop through 3 lists and get 3 columns in Python?

Tags: python

I have three lists list1 is "Car Models" list2 is "price per galon (mpg)" and list3 is "total price for one year". I'm able to loop through the 3 columns, but I don't know how to get 3 columns one after the other. Please someone help me. Thank you in advance!!

Heres my code:

```
modelName = ['Toyota', 'Nissan',  'Honda']
fuelEfficiency = [15.0, 20.0, 30.0]
for i in range(len(modelName)):
print (modelName[i])

for i in range(len(fuelEfficiency )):
print (fuelEfficiency[i])

priceGas = 2.41

totalCost1 = (10000 * priceGas)/15.0
totalCost2 = (10000 * priceGas)/20.0
totalCost3 = (10000 * priceGas)/30.0

print (totalCost1)
print (totalCost2)
print (totalCost3)
```

The output I want is this:

```
MODEL    COST(MPG) TOTALCOST
Toyota   15.0      1606.66  
Nissan   20.0      1205.0
Honda    30.0      803.33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
modelName = ['Toyota', 'Nissan',  'Honda']
fuelEfficiency = [15.0, 20.0, 30.0]
priceGas = 2.41
totalCost1 = (10000 * priceGas)/15.0
totalCost2 = (10000 * priceGas)/20.0      # totalCost = list(map(lambda x: (10000*priceGas)/x, fuelEfficiency))
totalCost3 = (10000 * priceGas)/30.0
totalCost = [totalCost1, totalCost2, totalCost3]

print("Model", "Cost(MPG)", "TOTALCOST")
for x in range(3):
    print(modelName[x], fuelEfficiency[x], totalCost[x])
```

for more better format, use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/he/Documents/program2.py", line 7, in <module>
    totalcost = [totalcost1, totalcost2, totalcost3]
NameError: name 'totalcost1' is not defined

Comment: ohh sorry case sensitivity, its totalCost1, C is capital

Comment: @Hackraholic Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because every column that you want has the same amount of items, you only need to use one for loop.  You also need to make a totalCost array for this to work.

```
modelName = ['Toyota', 'Nissan',  'Honda']
fuelEfficiency = [15.0, 20.0, 30.0]

priceGas = 2.41

totalCost = [0, 0, 0] # Filler values
totalCost[0] = (10000 * priceGas)/15.0
totalCost[1] = (10000 * priceGas)/20.0
totalCost[2] = (10000 * priceGas)/30.0


for i in range(len(modelName)):
    print modelName[i], fuelEfficiency[i], totalCost[i]
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

I think below solution is more pythonic

```
modelName = ['Toyota', 'Nissan',  'Honda']
fuelEfficiency = [15.0, 20.0, 30.0]
priceGas = 2.41

totalcost = map(lambda x:(10000 * priceGas)/x,fuelEfficiency)

for a,b,c in zip(modelName,fuelEfficiency,totalcost ):
    print a,b ,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about looping parallel, I would highly recommend to use `zip`. See the below example!

```
modelName = ['Toyota', 'Nissan',  'Honda']
fuelEfficiency = [15.0, 20.0, 30.0]
priceGas = 2.41
totalCost1 = (10000 * priceGas)/15.0
totalCost2 = (10000 * priceGas)/20.0
totalCost3 = (10000 * priceGas)/30.0
totalcost = [totalCost1, totalCost2, totalCost3]

print ("Model", "Cost(MPG)", "TOTALCOST")
for i in zip(modelName, fuelEfficiency, totalcost):
    print (" ".join(map(str, list(i))))
```

OUTPUT : I am running Python3.4

```
Model Cost(MPG) TOTALCOST
Toyota 15.0 1606.6666666666667
Nissan 20.0 1205.0
Honda 30.0 803.3333333333334
```

Comment: but Im using python 3.4 and your code is not working.. any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas for working with data in a table-like (aka DataFrame) structure.

```
import pandas as pd

modelName = ['Toyota', 'Nissan',  'Honda']
fuelEfficiency = [15.0, 20.0, 30.0]
priceGas = 2.41

df = pd.DataFrame({'MODEL': modelName, 'COST(MPG)': fuelEfficiency})
df['TOTALCOST'] = (10000 * priceGas) / df['COST(MPG)']

print df[['MODEL', 'COST(MPG)', 'TOTALCOST']].to_string(index=False)
```

This has the advantage that if you end up wanting to do more advanced data manipulation or formatting, there are a lot of convenient options in the pandas.DataFrame data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this.

```
modelName = ['Toyota', 'Nissan',  'Honda']
fuelEfficiency = [15.0, 20.0, 30.0]
for i in range(len(modelName)):
    print (modelName[i])

for i in range(len(fuelEfficiency )):
    print (fuelEfficiency[i])

priceGas = 2.41

totalCost=[0]*len(fuelEfficiency)

for i in range(len(fuelEfficiency)):
    totalCost[i]=(10000 * priceGas)/fuelEfficiency[i]


print "Model     Cost      Totalcost"
for i in range(len(fuelEfficiency)):
    print modelName[i],fuelEfficiency[i],totalCost[i]
```

Arrange the output according to your need.